# How to solve this simple jQuery issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript in general. I noticed that if you insert an element via jQuery into the DOM and try to perform an action on that element later, it fails. For example:

I am adding a class of "listenToField" to all the input elements on the page:

```
$(function() {

$('input').addClass('listenToField');

});
```

Then when I add the second function:

```
$(function() {

     $('input').addClass('listenToField');

     // second function
     $('.listenToField').keydown(function() {

          alert('Hi There')

     });

});
```

It does not alert 'Hi There'.

However if I hardcode the class "listenToField" into the HTML inputs, the alert works. How can I still have it work when jQuery inserts the class dynamically without resorting to hard coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try jQuery's `live` method.

The `live()` method assigns events to elements that exist, and ones that will be created.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.listenToField').live('keydown', function() {
   alert('Hi there!');
})
```

Comment: He isn't creating new elements though, he is just applying a class then trying to select by the class. Don't you agree it makes more sense to just skip the class application part? I guess there could be another reason why, but it is not apparent in the question.

Answer (score 3):

@jesus.tesh provides a correct workaround, but the reason this is not working as you expect can be found [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_doesn.27t_an_event_work_on_a_new_element_I.27ve_created.3F).

Jquery only works on elements that exist when it is loaded.  You need to do further manipulation as explained in the FAQ if you need it work against elements that you create.

Comment: Good info, thanks for adding it. It is good to answer the question, but better to teach. +1 for you

Answer (score 1):

Just cut out the middleman:

```
(function() {
     $('input').keydown(function() {
          alert('Hi There')
     });
});
```

You are applying the class to all inputs anyway, so just attach the keydown event instead. You can still apply the class if you need it for CSS styling too.

Comment: I simplified it for the example. I am actually adding the class to input fields that failed form validation. Which added a red border to all those inputs in addition to the "listToField" class. So later when the user starts to fill in the missing info I will remove the border. Anyway I just wanted to know the solution because I'm sure it will pop up in other projects.

Comment: Sure. Check out the info ChrisW added. It should help you get it working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, why take two steps? jQuery is chainable. The return value of a jQuery function is the jQuery object.

```
$("input").addClass("listenToField").keydown(function () { alert("Hi There"); });
```

Don't go too overboard with this. When jQuery chains get too long, they become difficult to read.